# How to convert code formula to excel data validation formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't have any experience with creating excel data validation formulas.

I have 2 code formulas, which are generated in java code, which are coming from excel data validations:

1. `COUNTA('User Input Sheet'!A:A)-4`
2. `IF(COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A5),COLUMN(A5),1,1,"User Input Sheet") & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(AJ5),COLUMN(AJ5))))=0, "","POP")`

Can someone help me how to write the data validation formula for the above two, as I have to use for different cells, but don't know how to put in cell data validation ?

Comment: Providing more information on what it is you're actually trying to do, will help you, as well as helping anyone who's trying to help you. See possible/best guess) answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Providing more information on what it is you're actually trying to do, will help you, as well as helping anyone who's trying to help you. e.g.:
Your 1st formula returns the number of non-empty cells in column A of a sheet, less 4.
But you don't say if the cell being validated needs to be more, less, the same or not the same as that. If you know the answer to that, the formula as is (with = in front) will work directly in the Data Validation 'value range' fields. e.g.:

[image]

The above example validates that a cell value is between zero and the results of the formula.
Suggest adapting and applying that, and if you're not getting the expect result, explain what you were aiming for, what you did, and what the results are.

=====================================================
The second formula is more problematic in terms of trying to guess what it is you're trying to do.
One thing I'll point out first thought: it uses INDIRECT in a completely unnecessary way (and that's inherently unwise). So the first thing to do is covert to a direct reference per:

```
=IF(COUNTA('User Input Sheet'!A5:J5)=0, "","POP")
```

But even then, you have a formula that returns a zero-length string ("") or literal 'POP' (based on A5:J5 being empty or not).
And it's unclear how you intend to use that to validate a cell. One guess would be the user has to enter "POP" or nothing (depending on A5:J5 being populated or not). But that seems to be an odd thing to do.